# Tikzpicture coordinates don't appear in plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to get 8 points with error bars plotted with Tikzpicture. I've already done a couple of plots but in this one the marks with the coordinates 6 and 8 aren't plotted.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{text}
\label{key}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ]
    \addplot + [only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]coordinates{
    (2,1.101) +- (0,0.0519)
    (1,1.276) +- (0,2.81)
    (3,-0.009) +- (0,0.577)
    (4,2.261) +- (0,1.27)
    };  
    \addplot + [only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]coordinates{
    (5,3.567) +- (0.747)
    (6,4.817) +- (0,3.44)
    (7,2.1133) +- (0.616)
    (8,-0.741) +- (0,3.51)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've supplied only one coordinate for the error bars, while you should have two, as in the other cases. I.e. `+- (0,y)`, instead of `+- (y)`, as you have now. Seems `pgfplots` just silently ignores that point when the coordinate specification is wrong.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{text}
\label{key}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ]
    \addplot + [only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]coordinates{
    (2,1.101) +- (0,0.0519)
    (1,1.276) +- (0,2.81)
    (3,-0.009) +- (0,0.577)
    (4,2.261) +- (0,1.27)
    };  
    \addplot + [only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]coordinates{
    (5,3.567) +- (0,0.747)
    (6,4.817) +- (0,3.44)
    (7,2.1133) +- (0,0.616)
    (8,-0.741) +- (0,3.51)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was simple. Thanks I didn't notice.